# ecrecover returns incorrect address

Tags: contract-design, ethers.js, contract-debugging, signature, keccak

I use these contract functions to verify signed message:

```
function verify(
        address to,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 nonce,
        bytes memory signature
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        address from = owner();

        console.log("from contract");
        bytes32 messageHash = getMessageHash(from, to, amount, nonce);
        console.logBytes32(messageHash);
        bytes32 ethSignedMessageHash = getEthSignedMessageHash(messageHash);
        console.logBytes32(ethSignedMessageHash);
        address addr = recoverSigner(ethSignedMessageHash, signature);
        console.log(addr);

        return recoverSigner(ethSignedMessageHash, signature) == owner();
    }

    function getMessageHash(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 nonce
    ) public pure returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encode(from, to, amount, nonce));
    }

    function getEthSignedMessageHash(bytes32 _messageHash)
        public
        pure
        returns (bytes32)
    {
        return
            keccak256(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32",
                    _messageHash
                )
            );
    }

    function splitSignature(bytes memory sig)
        public
        view
        returns (
            uint8,
            bytes32,
            bytes32
        )
    {
        require(sig.length == 65, "Invalid signature length");

        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;

        assembly {
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }
        console.logUint(v);
        console.logBytes32(r);
        console.logBytes32(s);
        return (v, r, s);
    }

    function recoverSigner(
        bytes32 _ethSignedMessageHash,
        bytes memory _signature
    ) public view returns (address) {
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = splitSignature(_signature);

        return ecrecover(_ethSignedMessageHash, v, r, s);
    }
```

But when I call it from js, it always gives me "Wrong signature" error, which is `require()` that checks `verify()` is equals to true.

To check contract functions I created js script, that mimic contract functionality with ethers.js:

```
async function info(signer, from, to, amount, nonce) {
        const payload = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
            ["address", "address", "uint256", "uint256"],
            [from, to, amount, nonce]
        )

        const array = ethers.utils.arrayify(payload)
        const hashed_payload = ethers.utils.keccak256(array) // message hash in contract
        console.log("Message Hash: ", hashed_payload)
        const types = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(
            ["string", "bytes32"],
            ["\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hashed_payload]

        )
        console.log("Eth signed message: ", types) // eth signed message 

        const signature = await signer.signMessage(array);
        console.log("Signature: ", signature)
        const sig = ethers.utils.splitSignature(signature);
        console.log("Signature:", sig);
        console.log("Recovered:", ethers.utils.verifyMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(payload), sig));
        console.log("++++")
```

The problem is that information from hardhat console and from js script is identical. Here it is:

```
// from js:
Message Hash:  0xe0ad70fdc7e7a60160b483c98583ee4a9ed173709bab8e802628279ce64749c8
Eth signed message:  0x030deb535a9f28fcf9d3cc003d7e1889e793f1e53c9abde29b8a6c3a8e04b065
Signature:  0xd7e114deb528f8ca0d0926865febaaf9cf10583f694a9b92aac4abe33a92a7334b441c3c9936767f58d537cc6ab46c6cd5bc92c244afc5522385d3b8f22bc0ee1c
Signature: {
  r: '0xd7e114deb528f8ca0d0926865febaaf9cf10583f694a9b92aac4abe33a92a733',
  s: '0x4b441c3c9936767f58d537cc6ab46c6cd5bc92c244afc5522385d3b8f22bc0ee',
  _vs: '0xcb441c3c9936767f58d537cc6ab46c6cd5bc92c244afc5522385d3b8f22bc0ee',
  recoveryParam: 1,
  v: 28,
  yParityAndS: '0xcb441c3c9936767f58d537cc6ab46c6cd5bc92c244afc5522385d3b8f22bc0ee',
  compact: '0xd7e114deb528f8ca0d0926865febaaf9cf10583f694a9b92aac4abe33a92a733cb441c3c9936767f58d537cc6ab46c6cd5bc92c244afc5522385d3b8f22bc0ee'
}
Recovered: 0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266
++++

from contract
0xe0ad70fdc7e7a60160b483c98583ee4a9ed173709bab8e802628279ce64749c8 // message hash
0x030deb535a9f28fcf9d3cc003d7e1889e793f1e53c9abde29b8a6c3a8e04b065 // eth signed message
28 // v
0xd7e114deb528f8ca0d0926865febaaf9cf10583f694a9b92aac4abe33a92a733 // r
0x4b441c3c9936767f58d537cc6ab46c6cd5bc92c244afc5522385d3b8f22bc0ee // s
0x63087790b2ffbb189b8e36508ed97f1749500432 // recovered address
0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266 // address correctly recovered in js, so u can see, they are not equal
```

With this outputs and code it seems like `recoverSigner()` with `ecrecover()` and `ethers.utils.verifyMessage()` works differently, but this is unlikely. I'm almost sure, there's mistake I just can't see.

Please, help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing signature generation on my frontend with `ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256()` method (twice for functions in this example, if check needed). It seems like `ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder()` works differently.

So, the right combination was solidityKeccak256 signature generation on frontend + using `abi.encodePacked()` in contract functions instead of `abi.encode()`

Refer to this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/111549/cant-validate-authenticated-message-with-ethers-js) to see another example.